# Priming Summary Fields

Tags: contacts, summaryfields

I hope you can help. I am new to CiviCRM and writing a custom Summary Field.

I have written the new field and the trigger, but I am confused about how this will count all of the values for before today. Is there a place in the extension I need to include another query? Is there other magic I am missing?

Thanks,
Penny

Answer (score 2):

When you go to **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Summary Fields**, the last option is *When should these changes be applied?*. Your summary fields will be primed at the time selected.  If you want to look at the code, the function is [sumfields_gen_data](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/blob/2646969738016a80f000c5bcedac1b1062a3d42c/sumfields.php#L1298).

[image]